# github.com advanced markdown inside blockquote

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme, blockquote

I'm writing a `README.md` for one of my repositories on [`github.com`](http://github.com).
As part of this `README.md` I'd like to include a quote of another `README.md` (from another repository), which implies using advanced markdown inside the quote.

Eventually I'd like to see something like this:

---

- Item 1

  - Use the following:

    > - First level of quoted list
    >
    >   - Second level of quoted ***list***
    >   - > Nested *quote*
- Item 2

---

For now I'm trying to achieve this with the following markdown:

```
 * Item 1
    * Use the following   
        > * First level of quoted list
        >   *  Second level of quoted ***list***  
        >   * > Nested *quote*
 * Item 2
```

There are several online markdown editors out there that intend to simulate `github` markdown behavior: [ones](https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/#Zc4xDoJAEIXhej3FX08nB6A0sbExnkAG3WRkojvC9VnAhMLqFf9XPIRz6IvjgSTcihJPpXczn/LwAGpILcIpf0pgOqrhPe+vh3ZYLrEJquGqdx+6PyUiC6yz25aLljWuqJbflWYG) that work much better than `github` itself, [others](http://dillinger.io/) that are a bit more realistic, but in `github` it looks like this:

---

- Item 1

  - Use the following
    > * First level of quoted list > * Second level of quoted list > * > Nested quote
- Item 2

---

So it appears that `github` supports some simple markdown inside the block quote (like bold, italic etc.), but it won't support the advanced markdown (like lists, quotes etc.)

Is there any way to quote a complex markdown on `github`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub is picky about requiring blank lines (to create a new pagragraph) before starting a blockquote. This seems to do what you want:

```
* Item 1
    * Use the following

        > * First level of quoted list
        >     * Second level of quoted ***list***
        >
        >     * > Nested *quote*
* Item 2
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!